# (SOLVED) Magento 2.3.5 Category backend data-binding not working & Category Frontend Landing Pages not showing (Migrated Data from Magento 1.7x)

Tags: magento2, magento-1.7, magento2.3, magento2-migration-tool, magento2.3.5

The question I want to ask is this: How does knockout data binding work in Magento 2.3.5?

I have migrated data from *Magento 1.7.0.2 using Magento Data Migration Tool*.

The backend **Catalog -> Categories -> (any category)** does not pull the data from the database.  It seems the values are just defaults.

**See image showing current values for Category ID: 7 (Brands)**
[image: See image showing current values for Category ID: 7 (Brands)]
After finding the related tables I ran this:

```
SELECT block.content, eea.attribute_code, eea.attribute_id, cat.*, ccet.*, block.*
   FROM catalog_category_entity_int ccet
   INNER JOIN catalog_category_entity AS cat
   ON ccet.entity_id  = cat.entity_id 
   INNER JOIN eav_attribute eea ON 
   ccet.attribute_id  = eea.attribute_id
   INNER JOIN cms_block as block 
   ON block.block_id = ccet.value 
   WHERE eea.attribute_code = 'landing_page'
   AND ccet.entity_id = 7
   ORDER BY eea.attribute_code ASC;
```

The results of the database data for **ID 7 (as image above)**:

[image: The results of the database data for ID 7 (as image above)]

The query I ran targets `landing_page` attribute (all other attributes and categories have same issue as discussed here), which returns `brands-landing-page` (this is the correct item) and all other information - **Brands** category with **Brands Landing Page**.

The data-binding (or something else) does not work correctly.  This means I cannot save the Category,  (as Category Name is **EMPTY** but *required*).

How and where can I start to investigate what is wrong, how will I be able if Knockout (or PHP that populates the data and binds to Knockout) works correctly?

***Frontend also doesn't display the landing page for the categories where set.***

**Side notes**

- Most important thing - Data is migrated using `data-migration-tool:2.3.5` from **Magento 1.7.0.2**
- The landing pages also doesn't show on the **frontend** (same issue with bindings maybe?)
- No errors in log files, no errors displayed on page, or browser console
- I have two Store IDs - `0 admin` and `1 custom store`
  *Changing Store IDs from 0 to 1 has no effect!*

Thank you!

### SOLUTION:

My instance was 100% related to `data-migration-tool` that doesn't correctly update all the related tables.  See LitExtension Magento Migration or my answer below for tables involved.

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to **LitExtension Magento Migration** for pointing me in the right direction.  The issue is that `catalog_category_entity` and `eav_entity_attribute` tables does not have the same IDs set for `entity_type_id = 3`.

The issue is related to the data migration tool:

- The base install for Magento 2.3.5 already contains attribute sets with ID 1-9.  ID 3 seems to be named **Default**, and attached to `entity_type_id = 3` (category entity).
- Once you migrate data (at least in my case), you **have to rename the base install attribute set names (named Default_1, Default_2 etc) otherwise the data migration tool just fails.** *(it complains about duplicate IDs as far as I remember).*
- When you finally migrate data using `bin/magento migrate:data path/to/config.xml` then it inserts the source Magento 1 attribute sets into destination Magento 2 database.  In my case it inserted ID **112 in attribute_set** named *Default*, which is then also inserted into `eav_entity_attribute` for `entity_type_id = 3`.
- However `catalog_category_entity` still has `attribute_set_id` set as **3**, while `eav_entity_attribute` is **112**, thanks **LitExtension Magento Migration** for pointing this out.

The solution is either updating the attribute_set_id in `catalog_category_entity` table as he suggested or updating the `eav_entity_attribute` table.

- Confirm IDs in `eav_entity_attribute`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(attribute_set_id) FROM eav_entity_attribute AS eea 
INNER JOIN eav_attribute as eatt on eea.attribute_id = eatt.attribute_id 
WHERE eea.entity_type_id = 3;
```

For my installation running

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity cce;
```

will show me that there are IDs for `parent_id` already attached to 3, in other words, **inheriting attribute sets** so I had to update the `eav_entity_attribute` table instead.

```
UPDATE eav_entity_attribute AS eea SET eea.attribute_set_id = 3
WHERE eea.entity_type_id = 3;
```

Clear cache and refresh the Category page, or the frontend!

#### EDIT: (New migration from original answer)

#### Additional Information

Note: my **newer migration changed from attribute_set_id 112 to 121** so keep that in mind the slight difference of my original answer.

What I meant originally (that may not be clear) is that on migration some tables have some entries with the original IDs assigned while the other table related has the migrated ID assigned, so related tables have un-synced data.

Before applying the fixes you might have something like this in your migration attempt:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(attribute_set_id) FROM eav_entity_attribute AS eea 
INNER JOIN eav_attribute as eatt on eea.attribute_id = eatt.attribute_id
WHERE eea.entity_type_id IN (3);
```

This shows a `n attribute_set_id` that migration process attached the Magento 1 migrated data to `entity_type_id 3`.  In my case : `attribute_set_id 121`

- Finding the `attribute_set_id` information:

```
SELECT attribute_set_id, attribute_set_name FROM eav_attribute_set
WHERE attribute_set_id IN (3, 121);
```

Gives:

```
3     Default
121   Migration_Default
```

- Determining `catalog_category_entity` attached `attribute_set_id`:

```
SELECT COUNT(entity_id) FROM catalog_category_entity
WHERE attribute_set_id IN (121);
```

Returns **0**, *no entries found*.

- However:

```
SELECT COUNT(entity_id) FROM catalog_category_entity cce 
WHERE attribute_set_id IN (3);
```

Returns **471**, *these are all my categories that are detached from* `attribute_set_id 121`.

**Two solutions are possible:**

> - Update `471 rows inside catalog_category_entity to attribute_set_id 121` and then making sure the backend of categories work correctly.

> or *easier in my opinion*

- update the `eav_entity_attribute table` to use `attribute_set_id 3` instead of `121` (provided that you remember to make sure the attributes used in 3 and 121 attribute sets look the same).
  *Remember: `entity_type_id 3 is categories` so *only update this for categories, not other entity_type_id entities`**

```
UPDATE eav_entity_attribute AS eea SET eea.attribute_set_id = 3
WHERE eea.entity_type_id = 3;
```

Comment: Hi!  I'm having a similar issue, but from what I've seen in my DB, all entries for `catalog_category_entity.attribute_set_id = 3` (apart from root category), where for the row `eav_attribute_set.attribute_set_id = 3`, `eav_attribute_set.entity_type_id = 3`, and then in the corresponding row `eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = 3`, `eav_entity_type.entity_type_code = catalog_category`, which all seems correct?  Are you able to give any further pointers?  I'm migrating from 1.9.4.0 -> 2.3.5, the initial migration worked fine, this second migration is producing the same issues (404, data-binding)

Comment: Hi, not sure any other pointers to give : other than making sure you also checked `eav_entity_attribute` table to see if the join I specified in my original answer returns results with `eav_attribute` for `entity_type_id = 3` (which you have already confirm is `catalog_category`.  From what I remember on this issue is that migrated Ids were detached for all these mentioned tables, some tables still had `3` but then `eav_entity_attribute` has `112`.  I am busy with a new migration and once I get this error again (I'm sure I will!) I will try to assist more if this is still not helfpul.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, I'll check that thanks!  That select was returning empty, I'm guessing it shouldn't?

Comment: Exactly correct, it should show you some entries, it means that your migrated IDs for `eav_entity_attribute` knows nothing of `entity_type_id 3` in other related tables.   For reference, I have ran this just now on a 'semi-working migration' database:

`attribute_set_id, 3, 99` - so I have two attribute_sets attached to `categories 3`

Comment: I think I'm going to roll back the codebase to 2.3.3 as that was the version the initial successful data migration took place on, probably wasn't a great idea to upgrade the site in the middle of a build anyway

Comment: Yes, I am also suffering with new `2.3.5` migration from Magento 1 which does not work properly, including some decisions Magento 2 devs made with recent M2 version that does not make sense to me unfortunately.  For instance, the fact that `core_config_data` table does not import data when using `app:config:import`, so locks everything in backend :/  Delete them from file, and you sit with `default settings`... 
At least give us the option to import `system_config` settings as well. Good luck!

Comment: It's insane isn't it!  Thanks, good luck to you too :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the **eav_entity_attribute** table with **eav_entity_type = attribute_set_id = 3** whether the **attribute of category** is assigned with **attribute set**

Comment: Do you mean for instance:  

`SELECT DISTINCT(attribute_set_id) FROM eav_entity_attribute AS eea
INNER JOIN eav_attribute as eatt
on eea.attribute_id = eatt.attribute_id 
WHERE eea.entity_type_id = 3;`  

This returns ID **'112'** only, then running  
`SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity cce WHERE cce.attribute_set_id = 112;` returns **empty resultset**.  
Is that what you meant? Thank you?

Comment: Also, how many **attribute_set_id** items are there supposed to be?  I have about a 100 attribute sets, do they all need to be attached to a category, or is it just one or two specific?

Comment: Please run also this query: update catalog_category_entity set attribute_set_id = 121

Comment: it's just only one attribute set with id = 121

Comment: I have done this about five minutes ago just to see the effect.  The ID was **112**, but when I inspected catalog_category_entity, there was an ID of **3** instead of **112**.  

I did the inverse as your suggestion though : 
`UPDATE eav_entity_attribute AS eea SET eea.attribute_set_id = 3
WHERE eea.entity_type_id = 3;`  - updating _eav_entity_attribute_ rather, because the inheriting attributes have 'parent_id' as 3.

This seems to work!  Thanks so much :)

Comment: No problem! :) please upvote for my answer so that it could help those who are in the same case.

Comment: I have upvoted but since I am a new member, it does not add.  I have also accepted the answer. Thanks again.