# Category Name and URL Key issue / Admin / Migration from 1.9.1.0 to 2.4.2

Tags: url-rewrite, magento2.4, data-migration, category-attribute, url-key

I'm facing an issue further to data migration from magento 1.9.1.0 to 2.4.2 in Admin > Store / Configuration / Category

Categories name and url_path are in the database, Category name also.

Category names are well displayed in navigation tree on the left **but Category Name field and Search Engine Optimization > URL key remain empty...(see pic)**

All categories url are broken (404) on front store

[image: admin category url key empty magento 2.4.2]

When I try update data manually in empty fields, I've Error on save : *"URL key for specified store already exists." cannot save category"* with empty url '.html'

[image: manual data saving error]

Of course all reindex, cache flushing etc have been ran.

If you have an idea to fix it, that would be great !

Comment: refer to this for efficient fix > https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/313280/solved-magento-2-3-5-category-backend-data-binding-not-working-category-fron

Answer (score 1):

My intuition tells me that you have the correct category name and url on the default store, but the migration saved the store values as null or empty string somehow. Check your database and verify the values stored on all stores/ scopes for those properties.

Comment: thanks, but all stores values looks good... might it be the attibute ID ? the category is set to 9 when it's 3 on default Magento 2... I saw some issues about it

Comment: yeah, it could be a mismatch over attribute ids, but I wouldn't necessarily count on M2 attribute ID number. however, check the results of the following query `SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_id IN (3,9);`  or replace with the IDs you suspect are probably the issue.

Comment: made both : check consistency with migrated Ids > OK, Reset to Magento default Ids an check consistancy > OK, but getting Categories Names and url_keys still NOK :(

Comment: hmm, sorry to hear this. it's very difficult to imagine what's going on, but if there is something popping to my mind, i will write here.

Comment: thanks very much :)

Comment: can you run a query for me? `SELECT DISTINCT(attribute_set_id) FROM eav_entity_attribute AS eea 
INNER JOIN eav_attribute as ea on eea.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id 
WHERE eea.entity_type_id = 3;` it will show you which is the attribute set id that is attached to the category entity ID. if the result is anything but 3 (which is the Default attr set used for categories), then this might be the thing going on with your values missing.

Comment: Hi, yeah I know from where you found this and thanks a lot, this is the key ! :) https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/313280/solved-magento-2-3-5-category-backend-data-binding-not-working-category-fron

Comment: heya! well it's not from that post, but glad that now i know a written reference to the problem and some1 actually described it in detail there. i discussed your scenario with a colleague and the blame fell on the migration tool and that's why i asked you about it. i suggest you then write an answer to your question and mark it as solution so others see it too. cheers!