# Magento 2, after data migration, cms category page blank for categories not in level1

Tags: magento2-migration-tool, magento2.4.3

I have an issue with migrating a store from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.4.3-p2.

All the data seems to be properly migrated, I can see the cms category page for root category and any other root category but when I try to edit a category in level2, level3, etc... blank page with no errors in logs and front.

I tried to move a category from level3 (for example) to root level, then I can edit it and then, move back to the initial position.

I checked data in catalog_category_entity* tables to find the error but unable to find it.

I can't create a new category either, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to related tables not having 'linked' data. Data migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2 is really a trial-and-error issue, and most likely will not work 100% on first migration.

#### Potential issue one

> Related to `catalog_category_entity` and `eav_entity_attribute` tables

You can look at my [question and answer here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/313280/solved-magento-2-3-5-category-backend-data-binding-not-working-category-fron) that discussed migration fixes for related table data of `catalog_category_entity` and `eav_entity_attribute`.

This is only one potential issue, the other could be related to the **attribute sets for entity 3 (category most likely) not assigned its correct groups** (from your description of 'Edit' it's not clear if you immediately have a crash on clicking any category or 'On Save/Move').

#### Potential Issue Two

> Related to `eav_attribute_group` and `attribute_set_id`

Try joining these tables and see if you find information for the `attribute_set_id` for the categories (this will be the one defined in all your categories in `catalog_category_entity`.

#### Summary

In summary, these groups, entities, attribute set IDs should be linked to the categories, if one of these are not, categories will not work correctly.

The tables I am talking about related to this discussion are these:
*So INNER JOIN (OR LEFT JOIN TO SEE NULL VALUES) your data on the matching IDs*, you will see the if things are not linked correctly.

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity cce;

SELECT * FROM eav_attribute_group eag;

SELECT * FROM eav_entity_attribute eea;

SELECT * FROM eav_attribute_set;
```

At the moment these are the ideas I have for you to start investigation.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried everything similar to your steps and I found the solution, disabling all plugins and testing one by one and I found the problem, it is because we have disabled backend search with a plugin and using algolia at the same time.